# How to get all days in one table a date range even if no data exists also in SQL Server

Tags: mysqli

I have one table name called Tab1. I would like to get all date even if any one of the days is missing also.

```
 +-------------------+--------------------------+
 |Name               | dateCheck                |
 +-------------------+--------------------------+
 | 1                 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000  |
 | 2                 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00.000  |
 | 3                 | 2016-01-05 00:00:00.000  |
 | 4                 | 2016-01-07 00:00:00.000  |
 +-------------------+--------------------------+
I need output like below :
 +-------------------+--------------------------+
 |Name               | dateCheck                |
 +-------------------+--------------------------+
 | 1                 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000  |
 | 2                 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00.000  |
 | 0                 | 2016-01-03 00:00:00.000  |
 | 0                 | 2016-01-04 00:00:00.000  |
 | 3                 | 2016-01-05 00:00:00.000  |
 | 0                 | 2016-01-06 00:00:00.000  |
 | 4                 | 2016-01-07 00:00:00.000  |
```

Comment: Please incldue the rest of your data.

Comment: if i include data why ask question on stackoverflow,,my problem is solved but i have not data on between date

Answer (score 0):

You may use a calendar table:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t2.Name, 0) AS Name,
    t1.dateCheck
FROM
(
    SELECT '2016-01-01' AS dateCheck UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-01-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-01-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-01-04' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-01-05' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-01-06' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2016-01-07'
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.dateCheck = t2.dateCheck;
```